# systemd show the maximum memory a .service has used

Tags: memory, systemd

I can see the current memory usage of a `systemd` service with `systemctl show -p MemoryCurrent update-data.service` (after I've set `MemoryAccounting=yes`).

Is there anyway to see, from systemd, the maximum amount of memory a service has used in it's lifetime?

This service is called from a `.timer` to update, and process, some data, and then stop. I'd like to know the maximum amount of memory each run of the service has used. I don't want to *limit* the memory, just report the maximum that `MemoryCurrent` has ever had.

systemd version v245 on ubuntu linux focal (20.04) or later.

Comment: systemd is quite feature heavy already, but I don't think that metrics collection/storage is included yet. I'd go the route of exporting metrics and collecting them in a dedicated solution like prometheus https://github.com/prometheus-community/systemd_exporter for example